# Dumping and sharing software for old Sharp calculator

Tags: hardware, sharp-el9000, dump

I have an old programmable Sharp calculator ([Sharp EL-9000 SUPER SCIENTIFIC](http://www.calculator.org/Pages/calculator.aspx?model=EL-9000&make=Sharp)) which I used extensively back in the day. I would like to dump all the software I wrote, and be able to share it.

[image: Sharp EL-9000]

I vaguely remember its manual mentioning the existence of a serial cable, but I long lost the book.

Is there an existing toolkit to do back up the software? Is there some specific format or site where I can upload my code to share it, or should I just use GitHub?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [Sharp CE-139T serial cable](http://www.imslsoft.com/xlinkwin.htm#Cables) (included in the Sharp CE-490W and CE-491W packages) or equivalent. But this cable is hard to find.

A similar cable is the CE-136T (included in the CE-390 package) which is not quite so hard to find but it only works in DOS because it requires exact timing. Maybe you can rig something up with a Raspberry Pi or Arduino to transfer the data to Windows.

Or get the [Sharp CE-50P printer & cassette port](http://sharppocketcomputers.com/index.htm#printers) and print out your programs, then scan them in; or attach a digital recorder to the cassette interface and save your programs to uncompressed .wav. This assumes the EL-9000 can export programs through the serial port. I couldn't find the manual online. Maybe you could scan it in and post it to [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/manuals)?